Avoid casting to string in parameterized query on JSON column, MySQL
To avoid SQL injection, we use a parameterized query with ActiveRecord, such as:
House.where("year_built > ?", 2000)

which works great (the example above is not optimal, because it could just as well be House.where(year_built: [2000..]) but it's just for context).
However, when using a JSON column, there's a problem, the value passed to WHERE is always converted to a string, e.g. "2000" instead of 2000. This won't work:
House.where("data->'$.year_built' > ?", 2000)

WHERE (data->'$.yearBuilt' > '2000')" won't find any result as we're comparing integer to string.
Is there a way to force the parameterized query in Rails to cast ? to a number always?

looks like this is the way to go, thanks @engineersmnky !

What happens if you do House.where("data->'$.year_built' > ?::int", 2000) or House.where("data->>'$.year_built'::int > ?", 2000)

@engineersmnky the caveat here is that the question is for MySQL and not Postgres. I missed it too as it's way on the end of the title.

@max no one missed anything the OP changed it after the fact. I originally inquired and provided Arel to produce the SQL. The original answer was Postgres

@engineersmnky sneaky.

Sorry my bad, but thanks @max for your solution
After all the problem is on Rails end: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44312

No matter what you passed as the right hand you're still going to run into an issues as -> is just a shorthand for JSON_EXTRACT and returns a quoted value.  Everything I encountered when researching this just made me hate MySQL more. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract
